# Porque IBUS cambio la distribucion de mi teclado en Lubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

estoy usando linux Lubuntu desde hace unas semanas y por defecto instale la distribucion de espanol latinoamericano, sin embargo, ahora instale el software ZOOM con sus dependencias, entre ellas se encontraba IBUS, y al reiniciarlo ahora usa el teclado ingles, y solo se puede cambiar al espanol de espana y no se encuentra el teclado latinoamericano y no logro cambiarlo, no encuentro informacion al respecto. como podria solucionarlo y cambiarlo?. muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Christian, si no me equivoco la versión de ibus que debes tener es 1.5.26 (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS). Parece ser que las distribuciones latam fueron incluidas en la lista negra por lo que no te aparecerán listadas con `ibus list-engine` o en ibus-setup. Aunque esto [se corrigió en ibus 1.5.27](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/commit/82e38d9e1c06e7fdc0816fe08f4021b8c1cdff10),  para versiones previas tal vez [esta respuesta en Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/704228) te sea de ayuda.